# SQL Server query with extremely large IN clause results in numerous queries in activity monitor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server 2014 database. Table with 200 million rows.

Very large query with HUGE IN clause.

I originally wrote this query for them, but they have grown the IN clause to over 700 entries.  The CTE looks unnecessary because I have omitted all the select columns and their substring() transformations for simplicity.

The focus is on the **IN clause**.  700+ pairs of these.

```
WITH cte AS (
           SELECT *      
           FROM AODS-DB1B
           WHERE  
           Source+'-'+Target
    IN
    (
    'ACY-DTW',
    'ACY-ATL',
    'ACY-ORD',
    :
    : 700+ of these pairs
    :
    'HTS-PGD',
    'PIE-BMI',
    'PGD-HTS'
    )

    )

    SELECT *
    FROM cte
    order by Source, Target, YEAR, QUARTER
```

When running, this query shoots CPU to 100% for hours - not unexpectedly.

There are indexes on all columns involved.

**Question 1**: Is there a better, or more effecient way to accomplish this query other than the huge IN clause?  Would 700 UNION ALLs be better?

**Question 2**: When this query runs, it creates a Session_ID that contains 49 "threads" (49 processes that all have the same Session_ID).  Every one of them an instance of this query with it's "Command" being this query text.

21 of them SUSPENDED, 
14 of them RUNNING, and 
14 of them RUNNABLE.

This changes rapidly as the task is running.

WHAT the *heck* is going on there?  Is this SQL Server breaking the query up into pieces to work on it?

Comment: Do source = xxx AND target = yyy instead.

Comment: Show us the query plan.  The actual `.SQLPLAN` file, not just a screen capture.

Comment: Put the IN values in a table? The concatenation in the where clause would prevent any index use

Comment: Alex.  Put the IN clause items in a table and JOIN the tables?  Is that what you mean?  I could certainly do that.

Comment: Yes, if its static data it belongs in a table with an index, if its dynamic a temporary table; IN does not scale well.

Comment: Alex, what would that JOIN look like.  Wouldn't it still require IN()?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recommend you store your 700+ strings in a permanent table as it is generally perceived as bad practice to store that much meta data in a script. You can create the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.LookUp(Source varchar(250), Target varchar(250))

CREATE INDEX IX_Lookup_Source_Target on dbo.Lookup(Source,Target)

INSERT INTO dbo.Lookup (Source,Target)
SELECT 'ACY','DTW'
UNION
SELECT 'ACY','ATL'
.......
```

and then you can simply join on this table:

```
SELECT * FROM [AODS-DB1B] a
INNER JOIN dbo.Lookup lt ON lt.Source = a.Source 
                         AND lt.Target=a.Target
ORDER BY Source, Target, YEAR, QUARTER
```

However, even better would be to normalise the `AODS-DB1B` table and store `SourceId` and `TargetId` INT values instead, with the VARCHAR values stored in `Source` and `Target` tables. You can then write a query that only performs integer comparisons rather than string comparisons and this should be much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Put all of your codes into a temporary table (or permamnent if suitable).....

```
SELECT *      
FROM AODS-DB1B
INNER JOIN NEW_TABLE ON Source+'-'+Target = NEWTABLE.Code
WHERE  
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a temp table with all those values and then JOIN to that table, it would make the process a lot faster

Comment: How...where is your example??

Comment: same as @Devart but using a #temp table instead, also using a JOIN not an IN or perhaps we can use an EXIST, I would also add more predicates if that's the case I personally don't think we should not be scanning all those 200 million records to get a results but not sure what's the logic in here

Comment: Read all the comments on the OP question....your answer looks more a comment than a real answer....be carefull with the low quality answers; some users love to give -1 to these type of answers(not my case).

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer from Jaco

Have an index on source, target

It may be worth giving this a try

```
where ( source = 'ACY' and target in ('DTW', 'ATL', 'ORD') )
   or ( source = 'HTS' and target in ('PGD') )
```